# How to get the count of rows in an ag-grid using TypeScript and Protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, ag-grid

I am trying to find the count of rows present in an ag-grid.
The Table structure ;looks like this:

```
<div class="ag-body-container" role="presentation" style="height: 500px; top: 0px; width: 1091px;">
<div role="row" row-index="0" row-id="0" comp-id="134" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0" style="height: 50px; top: 0px;  ">
<div role="row" row-index="1" row-id="1" comp-id="140" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0" style="height: 50px; top: 50px;  ">
<div role="row" row-index="2" row-id="2" comp-id="146" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0" style="height: 50px; top: 100px;  ">
<div role="row" row-index="3" row-id="3" comp-id="152" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0" style="height: 50px; top: 150px;  ">
<div role="row" row-index="4" row-id="4" comp-id="158" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0" style="height: 50px; top: 200px;  ">
```

There are few more rows present with same `class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0"`under some other div. so I cannot directly search for the rows with this class.

Appreciate any kind of help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css selector `div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]`, it only count rows in current viewport.  I noticed the demo on [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php), when you scroll down the grid, another batch rows will display. So if you grid also similar to this, above css selector can't get all data rows which not visible in viewport.